# How to set and append an array of objects in FireStore in JS / React JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
// sending contracts to user
export async function sendContractToOtherUser(email: string | any, contract: string) {
  try {

    let user : any = "";
    // search the users collection with the email and get the user id

    // Create a reference to the users collection
    const usersRef =  collection(db, "users");
    // Create a query against the collection.
    onSnapshot(usersRef, async(snapShot) => {
  
      snapShot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        if(doc.data().email === email) {
         user = doc.data();
        }} 
      );  
      console.log("//////user Found", user, typeof user, user.userID);

      // An Array which Contains an object
      const userContractData : any = [{
        userID : user.userID,
        contract: contract
      }];
      // setting the array 
      const newPendingContractRef : any = doc(db,"pendingContract", user.userID );
       await setDoc(newPendingContractRef,
        {...userContractData}
        , {merge: true});
      // console.log("/////////contract", pendingContract);

    });

  } catch (error) {
      console.log("/////////errror in sendContractToOtherUser", error);
  }
}
```

I want to append `userContractData` to the array present in the document (user.uid) of `pendingContract` collection. But what my code does that it only updates the already present  data at 0th index. How can I structure my `userContractData` along with the `setDoc` method that I can append into the array

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed setting value of first array item to the document. Try using `arrayUnion()` to push elements to an array:

```
await setDoc(newPendingContractRef,
        { contract: arrayUnion(...userContractData) }
        , {merge: true});
```